# Concurrent git processes working on single repository

Tags: git, concurrency

I am writing some tooling for git (lets say it is another GUI) and I plan on running several git commands (using the command-line client) in parallel, so several processes may be accessing the repo at any time.

1. Is it fine to have several read-only (e.g. git log, git show, git status) commands run in parallel?
2. Will they really execute concurrently (i.e. is there internal lock serializing the accesses)?
3. What if there is a modifying command executed? Will it be serialized properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is it fine to have several read-only ... commands run in parallel?

Yes.  Unfortunately, the list of which commands are actually read-only is surprising: in particular, `git status` is not one of them.  More precisely, `git status` is read-only only if you run `git --no-optional-locks status`.  (All commands can be run this way, though `--no-optional-locks` only affects *optional* locks anyway, so it does nothing for other commands.)

> 2. Will they really execute concurrently (i.e. is there internal lock serializing the accesses)?

Mostly, but see (1).

> 3. What if there is a modifying command executed? Will it be serialized properly?

Define "properly".

Commands that make changes do lock against each other, but commands that encounter locking issues tend to just *fail*.  So if two Git commands are trying to get `index.lock` to both update the index, one wins and proceeds, the other loses and exits entirely.  Is that "properly"?  The repository remains intact, but one of the commands never really ran.

Truly read-only operations will generally see either the "before" state or the "after" state, but there is a potential for them to see a mixed state.  For instance, `git log` might read out six reference names in series, while some other command updates some of them.  In this case `git log` might get one or more "old" values and one or more "new" values for each reference name.

Comment: By "properly" I meant the write operation to either happen before or after a read operation, but not in the middle (so that a read sees "before" or "after" but not "middle" state).
I was also thinking of a kind readers-writers lock, where several reads can happen in parallel, but a write needs exclusive access.

Comment: Git definitely does not do that—readers can read locked items. (They will see only the old values.) Locking is generally for rewrites of the index and/or of references. Objects and packed objects are write-only, constructed in temporary files and renamed into place.